# Regex for extracting text in URL between a constant start position until the immediate next slash or the end of the string

Tags: sql, regex, url, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, extract

Trying to extract text using Snowflake’s REGEX_SUBSTR() function. I have a working solution using CASE WHENs to handle for the different scenarios, but I’d love a cleaner solution if one exists

These are the three possible scenarios and the text we want to extract:

1. https://someDomain.com/constant-string/EXTRACT
2. https://someDomain.com/constant-string/EXTRACT/someOtherText
3. [https://someDomain.com/constant-string/EXTRACT/someOtherText/someOtherText/…/someOtherText](https://someDomain.com/constant-string/EXTRACT/someOtherText/someOtherText/%E2%80%A6/someOtherText)

In all three scenarios, the domain can change and the number of backslashes can change, but the constant string will always be the same, and I always want to extract the text that immediately follows the constant string until the next backslash or, in cases where there are no other backslashes, until the end. The issue is that since the number of backslashes can change and that a URL doesn’t always end with a backslash, I’ve had to come up with a CASE WHEN with three different REGEX_SUBSTR() functions to make this work - this is fine, but looking for a one-liner REGEX_SUBSTR() solution

Here’s my current solution:

```
           WHEN CONTAINS(REGEXP_SUBSTR(url, '(constant-string/)(.*?)(/)', 1, 1, 'e', 2), '/') THEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(url, '(constant-string/)(.*)(/.*?)/', 1, 1, 'e', 2)
           WHEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(url, '(constant-string/)(.*?)(/)', 1, 1, 'e', 2) IS NOT NULL THEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(url, '(constant-string/)(.*?)(/)', 1, 1, 'e', 2)
           WHEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(url, '(constant-string/)(.*?)(/)', 1, 1, 'e', 2) IS NULL THEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(url, '(constant-string/)(.*)(/|$)', 1, 1, 'e', 2)
           ELSE 'None of These'
```

Comment: Perhaps just `REGEXP_SUBSTR(url, 'constant-string/([^/]+)', 1, 1, 'e', 1)`?

Comment: `/constant-string/(.*?)(?:/|$)`.

Comment: @Nick this worked! Mind explaining quickly what this is doing?

Comment: @Reilas will test yours out tomorrow. Thank you!

Comment: @NikhilKatti it's just matching everything after `constant-string/` that is *not* a `/` i.e. until it reaches a `/` or end-of-string and collecting that into group 1, which is then returned by `REGEXP_SUBSTR` because the `subexpr` value is 1

Comment: You can also look into https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/parse_url. This will parse your URL and you can just take the left part of the `path` before the first right slash.

Comment: If what you need to extract always comes after 4 backslashes, you can do `split(url,'/')[4]::varchar`

Comment: Thanks all! Lots of workable answers here

Answer (score 0):

1. Split the URL on the slashes to an array
2. Locate the constant string in the array
3. Get the next value in the array

```sql
select split('https://someDomain.com/constant-string/EXTRACT/someOtherText','/') ary,
array_position('constant-string'::variant, ary) index,
get(ary, index+1)::string extract;
```

| ARY | INDEX | EXTRACT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ["https:","","someDomain.com","constant-string","EXTRACT","someOtherText"] | 3 | EXTRACT |